# Entity Framework 5 caching issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

We are facing the following issue with Entity Framework 5:

Our application logic is that users can work on the same data from multiple computers.

Once one user query data, & the same data gets changed on another computer, he will not get the updated data until he restarts the application.

We already have the "Lazy Loading Enabled" option set to true & we don't want to disable this option.

We want the entity to query the database every time without caching.

How can we solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the constructor of your DbContext class:

```
    public DbContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
```

EDIT: I think that what you're asking for is not possible using Entity Framework. Entity Framework automatically will cache the object, because that's what it's built for.

Comment: I am sorry, We already have that option set to true, I have updated the question to clarify the issue.

Comment: To overcome this issue, I used the Refresh Method of the Entity's Container.